# Xamarin.Forms app freeze on launch (issue with startupWork.ContinueWith)

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin

We have a Xamarin.Forms app. Our latest update introduced an issue for some users (namely Samsung S3, Galaxy S7 Edge, and S5 Neo).

We can test and replicate in-house on S5 Neo. On launch, screen becomes unresponsive and looks like this:

[S5 Neo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BNXq.jpg)

Debugging leads me to think issue is with:

```
protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        Task startupWork = new Task(() =>
        {

        });


        startupWork.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        startupWork.Start();

    }
```

I have tried:

- Searching Google and SO
- [The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245926/the-current-synchronizationcontext-may-not-be-used-as-a-taskscheduler)
- [Top Level Task Causes Error "The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370904/top-level-task-causes-error-the-current-synchronizationcontext-may-not-be-used)

I'm running out of ideas. Can you help?

Comment: could provide more details about the startupwork and why is the intent inside it?

Comment: @shanranm I updated above whole functions and if intent I use directly then on next screen all side menu displaying blank with white background.